# Remove domain\username from search result

Tags: 2010, search

I implemented search core result component in my page.
  
My username is: "jack.antoun" on the servername "webserver"

When I put in the search box “jack" for example, the search results returns: "domain\username" which is "webserver\jack.antoun" in the description text. (Please note that I already remove author, date, and size)
  
How to remove the "domain\username" from being displayed in search results description ? 
Screeshot is under the following link:
[Search result display](http://www.balamand.edu.lb/english/test/search.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for adding more information. I would recommend adding a screenshot or include what specifically you are editing (page, web part, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You have to customize the XSLT of SearchCore Web Part. To do that I suggest you to download the result of your search as a XML file and use it on Visual Studio with the standard XSLT and start to modify it step-by-step.
For more information take a look here: http://salvatoredifaziosharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-add-custom-value-in-search-core.html